# SQL Get Rows Based on Column Value Frequency

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

| chef_name | chef_cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| mario | italian |
| jack | american |
| mario | italian |
| mario | american |
| jack | greek |
| jack | greek |

Let's say that each row represents a meal that each chef has made. But we want to find out from this table, what type of chef are these people?

We want to find the most-frequent `chef_cuisine` value for each chef.

How would you find this using SQL such that the result would read:

| chef_name | chef_cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| mario | italian |
| jack | greek |

Comment: You could select the count of each combination in a subquery and select the max count in an outer query

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only the tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @Chris yeah sorry I should have made this clear, I'm super new to SQL so I get the idea, but I'm more-so asking for like the syntax

Comment: What's the expected result if arnold has one american and one austrian?

Comment: @jarlh just pick either or

Comment: "just pick either one" is not very descriptive, in terms of SQL you might say "pick the first one" and you should also specify the sort sequence when making this statement.

Comment: @Alec Donald Mather - no, I should apologise - I just kind of thought you were a bit stuck on approach - looks like you have an answer which is slightly different but almost certainly more elegant

Comment: Someone still waiting for the dbms tag?

Comment: pretty sure he edited the question already to remove them

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather Its a good idea to include a name for your table, or even the actual create script in your post so that you can easily verify answers posted but also so there is consistency in our responses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by combining GROUP BY with a window function:

```
select chef_name, chef_cuisine
from (
  select chef_name, 
         chef_cuisine,
         dense_rank() over (partition by chef_name order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from the_table
  group by chef_name, chef_cuisine
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

This would return two "cuisines" if a chef has the same number of rows for each. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

Comment: I bet OP could benefit from an explanation before simply diving into window functions...

Comment: You could also use SQL Server's STRING_AGG function to group chef_cusine's that tie for top frequency into a single comma delimited value in one row, if you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

> If you're just starting out in SQL it is important that you understand the process, before you jump straight into the answer

You need to first break down your requirement into smaller parts that can each be easily solved

Frequency can be identified using the `COUNT()` function, so start by aggregating your recordset by *Grouping by* both the `chef_name` and the `chef_cuisine`:

```
SELECT chef_name, chef_cuisine, cuisine_count = count(1)
FROM the_table
GROUP BY chef_name, chef_cuisine
ORDER BY cuisine_count DESC
```

| chef_name | chef_cuisine | cuisine_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jack | greek | 2 |
| mario | italian | 2 |
| jack | american | 1 |
| mario | american | 1 |

You can see that this is already close to what you are looking for, this result set helps you to visualise the results, we just need to select the `chef_cuisine` that has the highest count for each `chef_name`.

One way to do this would be to select the first row (`TOP 1`) after sorting by the count in *descending* (`DESC`) order, a *first principals* approach would be to use an inline sub-query:

```
SELECT chef_name , (
    SELECT TOP 1 chef_cuisine
    FROM the_table lkp
    WHERE lkp.chef_name = t.chef_name
    GROUP BY lkp.chef_cuisine
    ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
   ) chef_cuisine
FROM the_table t
```

| chef_name | chef_cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| mario | italian |
| jack | greek |
| mario | italian |
| mario | italian |
| jack | greek |
| jack | greek |

To get the unique rows from this result, you could use `GROUP BY` or you could simply us `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DSTINCT chef_name , (
    SELECT TOP 1 chef_cuisine
    FROM the_table lkp
    WHERE lkp.chef_name = t.chef_name
    GROUP BY lkp.chef_cuisine
    ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC
   ) chef_cuisine
FROM the_table t
```

| chef_name | chef_cuisine |
| --- | --- |
| jack | greek |
| mario | italian |

---

These types of queries are pretty common, so most database engines have included support for *windowing queries*, which is effectively a short hand way of executing simple aggregates like *counting* or *row numbering* over a subset of the same results table, without you having to write a nested query or a table joined back onto itself.

Probably the most useful aspect of windowing queries is that they do not require you to alter the original result set, you can return *all* the rows from the original query with the results of the window query attached as additional columns.

[The response from a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66430299/1690217) is a good enough example of how to run to obtain the same results using the `DENSE_RANK()` window function

Comment: Great pedagogy here.